# Plot the average of different number of entries in a pandas DataFrame in a grouped bar chart

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-science

I have this [csv](https://pastebin.com/EH3CzHf8) which contains times measured for some algorithms over some matrices with a different number of cpus each time. Each cpu printed their times so the more cpus I used the more lines I had. (eg. if I used 1 cpu I had one measurement, if I used 2 i would have 2 measurements etc. going up to 64)

What I'm trying to do is plot in a grouped bar chart where each bar in the group is a different 'algo' entry, the x axis is the number of cores ('numtasks' in the csv) and the y axis is the average of all the cores in that group (eg. for 2 cores the average of the times of those 2, 4 cores the average of those 4 etc.).

(Edit: Kind of like [this](https://ibb.co/wwWbKW9))

I tried using pandas for a few hours with `pivot()`, `mean()` and `concat()`enating the results but to no avail.

I'd be glad if anyone could point me to the right direction, thanks in advance!

Comment: please post some input as text , and an expected output

Comment: @adirabargil something like [this](https://ibb.co/wwWbKW9)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand these are the attributes you want on a stacked bar chart.  The key steps are adjusting results using `unstack()` and `droplevel()`

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,1, figsize=[10,5],
                      sharey=False, sharex=False, gridspec_kw={"hspace":0.3})


(pd.read_csv("EH3CzHf8.txt")
 .groupby(["algo","numtasks"])["total"].mean()
 .to_frame()
 .unstack(0)
 .droplevel([0], axis=1)
 .plot(ax=ax, kind="bar", stacked=True)
)
```

### output

[image]

Comment: That seems to be *almost* what i want! Instead of stacked, i wanted them in a grouped bar chart like [here](https://ibb.co/wwWbKW9) . Also, half of those I've never seen so I will try to go through it and understand how that works.

Comment: Ok so i should have thought from the start but turning stacked to false gave me the result i wanted! Thank you!

Comment: glad to be of help - I also thought `stacked=False` provided a more meaningful plot.  Can you accept the answer, thanks

Comment: Sure, here you go! Also, could you maybe point me to some resources regarding the use of DataFrames and/or handling this type of data that you think i might find useful?

Comment: I'm self taught.... however I've not systematically been through any materials.  I've been working with data and data structures for 30 years so I go from the theory of data modelling and look for features that support that with the tech I'm using.

Comment: Understandable. Side question, as you can see from the csv i have the collumns 'search' 'build' and 'wait'. Is there a way to plot those in a stacked *AND* grouped bar chart? So, it will be like the above with 'stacked=False' but each bar will be stacked with those 3 values mentioned above

Comment: `df = (pd.read_csv("EH3CzHf8.txt")
 .groupby(["algo","numtasks"]).agg({"total":"mean","build":"mean","wait":"mean"})
 .unstack(0)
)
df.columns = df.columns.rename("time", level=0)
df.plot(ax=ax, kind="bar", stacked=False)
` will take in all the values.  Some are too small for scales.  NB `rename()` to clean up legend.